# New to Python: How to keep the first letter of each word capitalized?

Tags: python

I was practicing with this tiny program with the hopes to capitalize the first letter of each word in: john Smith.
I wanted to capitalize the j in john so I would have an end result of **J**ohn Smith and this is the code I used:

```
name = "john Smith"

if (name[0].islower()):
    name = name.capitalize()
print(name)
```

Though, capitalizing the first letter caused an output of: John **s**mith where the S was converted to a lowercase. How can I capitalize the letter j without messing with the rest of the name?

I thank you all for your time and future responses!
I appreciate it very much!!!

Comment: Maybe `print(name.title())` is what you are looking for.

Comment: To capitalize the first letter "without messing with the rest of the name": `name[0].upper() + name[1:]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @j1-lee pointed out, what you are looking for is the `title` method, which will capitalize each word (as opposed to `capitalize`, which will capitalize only the first word, as if it was a sentence).

So your code becomes

```py
name = "john smith"
name = name.title()
print(name) #> John Smith
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you should be using *str.title()*. However, if you want to reinvent that functionality then you could do this:

```
name = 'john paul smith'
r = ' '.join(w[0].upper()+w[1:].lower() for w in name.split())
print(r)
```

**Output:**

```
John Paul Smith
```

**Note:**

This is not strictly equivalent to *str.title()* as it assumes all whitespace in the original string is replaced with a single space

Comment: Also note that `title` also considers underscores as word separating.

Comment: @BlackBeans This answer is **not** intended as a replacement for *title()*. It merely demonstrates how the problem *could* be approached if OP insists on not using built-in functionality